# Windows Service stays in Starting state

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I have a Windows service written in CPP that I start manually. The service starts up just fine and works ok. However we have recently noticed in the Windows Services GUI that the service shows in the Starting state. Upon examining the Event Viewer it clearly shows that the service has entered the Running state.

Anyone got any nuggets of gold on this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, odd. At the risk of stating the obvious, have you tried refreshing the Windows Services GUI?

Comment: In addition to @cameron's advice, what is the output of `sc.exe query <service name>`?

Comment: One More thing: are you sure you eventually call `SetServiceStatus` with `SERVICE_RUNNING` from your ServiceMain method?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be an unaccounted for call to the SCM to start the service. Deleted the line and the problem went away.